# How can Iget different sounds for different notifications?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, notifications, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different notification sounds for sms and email?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/different-notification-sounds-for-sms-and-email)

I have a Samsung galaxy s2 with Android 4.0.4 Is there any way to set different tones for different notifications? For example, a different tone for SMS than for emails.

Answer (score 1):

Which SMS app are you using? The stock one? Most apps will let you set the notification sound in the application settings. Go to the SMS app and go to the settings in there.