# Disable sound alerts for new emails

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I have a Samsung Duos GT-S7562, running Android 4.0.4.

I have set up two email accounts on my device: Gmail and YahooMail. I want to stop the alert sound it plays each time I get an email. How do I do that?

ty,
Rajeev

Answer (score 3):

See below how to change your email notification sound, or how to disable it. My android is 2.3.5, gmail is 2.3.6.

You open the gmail app, menu > more > settings, tap in the account; in the very bottom there's an option "Labels to notify". In my case I have "Inbox", which I'm assuming is default; when you click on it, you have a few options:

- "Email notifications" - notifies in the status bar
- Ringtone - this is what you're looking for, you can set any ringtone or silent
- Vibrate - well, it vibrates ;)

Answer (score 0):

[This question answers it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/different-notification-sounds-for-sms-and-email)

But lets recap:

In Gmail press menu and go to More->Settings->Select the email account->Sound & vibrate...

Basically, should be a part of the settings within the app. I dont know for Yahoo but it's probably similar.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my driving mode was On in the quick menu. Once I turned it off, it didn't give me the audio email notification.