# Is there a way to automatically change notification ringer&volume, differentiating email, sms and calendar via profiles?

Tags: notifications, profiles

I'm aware of this [question about different notification settings for different apps.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1114/different-notification-sounds-for-sms-and-email) But changing the settings manually like that is time consuming. It would be nice to integrate these settings into profiles so:

- At night it would be nice to have SMS off, emails off and calendar on
- During the day however, it would be nice to have everything on
- On certain occasions, only sms and calendar notifications would be nice

... you can see the trend here, toggling different notifications on and off quickly would be a smart idea. Blackberry has had it for years. I understand that the way Android works makes this impossible. Why is there no API that allows apps to set other app's notification settings? Or would that make too much sense?

I have a Galaxy Nexus and Galaxy S3. Any solutions are appreciated. The new Blackberry has this feature but then I'd have no apps.

Comment: As *Is there an app for X* questions are off topic here (see our [FAQ]), I slightly rephrased yours. You might want to look at automation solutions like e.g. [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) or *Llama*. I use Tasker for similar things. But I'm afraid your absolute wish will be impossible to fulfill, as you can e.g. either say "no notifications", but not "no notifications from these apps only". But with *Tasker* and [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) you can come close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) app supports “LlamaTones” — notification sounds which change according to the current profile. See [this blog post](http://kebabapps.blogspot.ru/2012/01/ring-ring-ring-ring-ring-ring-ring.html) for the description by the app developer.

You could achieve what you want as follows:

1. Create separate profiles for every different configuration you want to have.
2. Edit one of profiles and create a LlamaTone named “SMS”; select a notification sound for it which should be used when that profile is active. To make the notification silent, select a “No Sound” ringtone (at least on CyanogenMod 9 it is available in the “Ringtones” group; if there is no such ringtone on your phone, you should be able to find a no-sound .mp3 and add it easily).

   Repeat this step to create LlamaTones for all other apps which need to be controlled separately (you can create a single LlamaTone for a group of apps which should use the same notification sound).
3. Now edit all other profiles and configure all LlamaTones there, setting notification sounds which are appropriate for these profiles.
4. Configure your apps to use the newly created LlamaTones as notification sounds.
5. You can either switch profiles manually, or configure Llama events to switch them according to the current time or any other available triggers.

Note that there is no way to set different volumes for different LlamaTones — the same notification volume is used, but this volume can be set in the profile. However, you can use a sound editor to change sound volume in audio files, and then use those audio files as custom notification sounds, e.g., [like this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/3545/11251).

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way Android works, one app cannot change another app's settings. In future versions of Android this could be made possible via an API like the Android Content Provider. Each app needs to provide the functionality for the other apps to change it's notification settings.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279954/changing-notification-settings-in-native-email-app/2280765