# How can I Have Separate Alerts for Email and SMS?

Tags: notifications, gmail, samsung-galaxy-s-4, go-sms

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.2.2. Currently both SMS and Email notifications have the same sound. Before I was on this phone I was on an iPhone and this was easy to change. I cannot find a way to distinguish between alerts.

In browsing this site for an answer I came across [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1114/8310) which had this answer:

> You can customize the Notification settings for both Gmail and Messaging in each of the apps separately.
>
> In Gmail press menu and go to More->Settings and look at the Notification settings section.
>
> In Messaging press menu then Settings and look at the Notification settings section.

I assume this answer is out-of-date because it doesn't work on the Galaxy S4.

I am using the Stock Gmail App for email and I use GO SMS PRO for messaging.

How do I change to separate alerts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change the notification sound on the **GMail** app you can do the following:

1. Open the GMail app and press the menu button (the one to the left of the Home button)
2. Press Settings and then choose the email address (not general settings)
3. Touch the word "Inbox sound & vibrate"
4. Click "Sound"
5. Then there is a popup for the choice of notification sound you want for your email.

For **GO SMS PRO**:

1. Press the same menu button
2. Settings
3. Advanced
4. Notification settings
5. Default notification settings
6. Select ringtone

Answer (score 0):

With [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=antx.tools.catchnotification) you can set up a different notification sound for each app on your phone. 
Launch it. Add "Messages" (com.android.mms) in apps list and set up sound for sms notification. Then add "Gmail" (com.google.android.gm) in apps list and set up sound for email notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Apps -> (Select App you'd like to change notification for) -> Notifications -> Other -> Sound